# Modifying and Displaying URL's in a Post Template using parse_url

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Custom Post Type with a template named `single-posttype.php`. I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to display certain information (price and links to the actual product).

All that is working good. However, I want to take the links that I input in the Custom Fields and modify them to remove any query strings and append my affiliate code. I have a function that uses `parse_url()` and works fine for my purposes. The problem is it's not showing the string when I try to display it in other parts of the page.

Here's the full code of my template: http://pastebin.com/SrWrQ15L

Here's the function in question and how I call it:

```
        $theme_link_raw = get_field('theme_link');
        $preview_link_raw = get_field('theme_preview_link');
        $author_link_raw = get_field('author_link');

        $theme_parts = parse_url("$theme_link_raw");
        $preview_parts = parse_url("$preview_link_raw");
        $author_parts = parse_url("$author_link_raw");

        $theme_link = $theme_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $theme_parts['host'] . $theme_parts['path'];
        $preview_link = $preview_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $preview_parts['host'] . $preview_parts['path'];
        $author_link = $author_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $author_parts['host'] . $author_parts['path'];

        function affiliatize($link, $parts) {

          switch ($parts['host']) {
            case "themeforest.net":
              echo $link . "?ref=gorrillamcd";
              break;
            case "www.elegantthemes.com":
              echo "http://www.elegantthemes.com/affiliates/idevaffiliate.php?id=22953" . "&" . $link;
              break;
            case "themefuse.com":
              echo $link . "?r=42892";
              break;
            default:
              echo $link;
              break;
          }
        }


        $theme_affiliate = affiliatize($theme_link_raw, $theme_parts);
        $theme_affiliate_preview = affiliatize($preview_link_raw, $preview_parts);
        $theme_author = affiliatize($author_link_raw, $author_parts);
```

I know it's probably not perfect, but I'm not very familiar with PHP (I'm a ruby guy myself), so I'm thinking there is a simple problem I'm not seeing. **Notice also this is a temporary hack. I plan to make it into a plugin, but that will take more time and learning and I'd like to go ahead and get it working now.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm stupid. I figured it was something simple.

In my function, I should have used `return` instead of `echo`. I was under the impression that `echo` was what's normally used since **every** example or tutorial I found on the internet for writing php functions used `echo`. At least now it makes more sense.